# Is this a viable technique for integration that I should persue exploring? Thoughts?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, substitution

I started with the integral of:

$$\int \frac{\ln(x)}{x}dx = \frac{\ln^2(x)}{2} + C$$

Which was very easy to integrate.
Then, I moved to a more difficult problem:
$$\int \frac{\ln(x-t)}{x} dx$$

I started by letting $t$ tend to some arbitrary, zero-like variable $O_t$.
Where some $a_0 - O_t = a_0$, but $O_t$ is not technically equal to zero. In other words, expressions containing $O_t$ cannot be simplified and compacted, but it behaves like zero when the cyclical nature of the integral pops up.

Using it, the DI method yields:
$$\int \frac{\ln(x-O_t)}{x}dx = \ln(x-O_t)\ln(x) - \int \frac{\ln(x)}{x-O_t}dx$$

Since this $O_t$ is technically equal to zero, then by definition:
$$\int \frac{\ln(x-O_t)}{x}dx = \int \frac{\ln(x)}{x-O_t}dx$$

Plugging this is, you find that:
$$\int \frac{\ln(x-O_t)}{x}dx = \ln(x-O_t)\ln(x) - \int \frac{\ln(x-O_t)}{x}dx$$

You can add the integral to both sides, and divide by two:
$$\int \frac{\ln(x-O_t)}{x}dx = \frac{\ln(x-O_t)\ln(x)}{2}+C$$

Then, in order to complete the problem, you can let $O_t$ re-approach $t$:

$$\int \frac{\ln(x-t)}{x}dx = \lim\int \frac{\ln(x-O_t)}{x}dx = \frac{\ln(x-t)\ln(x)}{2} + C$$

In order to test this, you can plug in $t=0$ to see this conclusion in action:
$$\int \frac{\ln(x-0)}{x} dx = \frac{\ln(x-0)\ln(x)}{2} + C = \frac{\ln^2(x)}{2} + C$$

Which indeed is correct.
Is this new "zero-substitution" technique for integration viable? Or does it have major gap holes. Should I pursue it and apply it to other integrals?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true that
$$\int \frac{\ln(x-t)}{x} \ dx = \frac{\ln(x-t)\ln(x)}{2} +C$$ in general because differentiating the right hand side we obtain
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\ln(x-t)}{x}+\frac{\ln(x)}{x-t}\right).$$
In the case where $t=0$ this does hold, but also if $t=0$ then
$$\int \frac{\ln(x)}{x} \ dx = \ln(x)^{2} - \int \frac{\ln(x)}{x} \ dx$$
and the result follows similarly as in your post without the need for $O_{t}$.